# Designing database where a comic can have many chapter

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm designing a database for a comic-reading website. Been wondering what is the proper way of designing it when; a comic have a table and a comic can have many chapter, so is it possible to create a chapter table for each comic every time a comic is created or is there a better standard way of doing it?

Imagine it like a post and a post have multiple comment; how do you design that?

[Diagram I made here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw8ju.jpg)

Comment: That diagram is already good design.

Comment: What is a `User` in this context?

Comment: @PM77-1 User means the person that create/upload the comic.

Comment: @jordiburgos but won't the chapters table be too cluttered/mixed up with all chapters from different comic inside one table.

Comment: @Nasx all the chapters should be stored to the chapters table. They have an ID field to identify the comic

Comment: So USER is an Author.  What is the relationship between Users and Chapters? Can a chapter have more than 1 author?

Comment: @PM77-1 no. A chapter can only have 1 author.

Comment: Can a User be an author of more than 1 Chapter in the same Comic?

Comment: @PM77-1 the author will automatically be the author of the chapter of the comic he created in the first place. So yes.

Comment: So you have `many-to-many` relationship between `User` and `Comic`. This indeed requires 3 tables: two main ones and an additional "link" table that has two foreign keys relating it to the two "main" tables.

Comment: @PM77-1 it's one-to-many since one `artist` can have many `comic`, but a `comic` can only have one `artist`.

Comment: Then why do you even need Chapters?

Comment: @PM77-1 Because one comic can have many chapter.

Comment: "create a chapter table for each ..." -- _No_.  Only one Chapter table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close with that diagram, you just need one more step. In the same way that you don't need a new "comic" table for each "artist", you don't need a new "chapter" table for each "comic". They can all coexist using relationships.

Change your chapter table so the primary key is some "chapter_id" and move the "chapter_no" to a regular column. Everything should work out once you've done that. You can query for a comic's chapters by looking up chapters where `comic_id = <some_id>` and even `orderby chapter_no` if you want them in order.

Comment: This make sense if I imagine it like this. Thanks for pointing out the chapter_id, I completely miss that.